# Amazon API SOAP code generation from WSDL, Intellij

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, wsdl, wsdl2java

I generated Java code from the Amazon WSDL found [here](http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl) in Intellij. It appeared to have worked great. However, as I followed the tutorial found on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/GSG/ImplementinganA2SRequest.html) I encountered a problem. The last line of the java code is calling a method itemSearch from the AWSECommerceServicePortType class. The only method description that was generated for that method was

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "ItemSearch", action = "http://soap.amazon.com/ItemSearch")
             @RequestWrapper(localName = "ItemSearch", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", className = "com.shopit.amazon.ItemSearch")
             @ResponseWrapper(localName = "ItemSearchResponse", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", className = "com.shopit.amazon.ItemSearchResponse")
             public void itemSearch(
    @WebParam(name = "MarketplaceDomain", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String marketplaceDomain,
    @WebParam(name = "AWSAccessKeyId", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String awsAccessKeyId,
    @WebParam(name = "AssociateTag", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String associateTag,
    @WebParam(name = "XMLEscaping", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String xmlEscaping,
    @WebParam(name = "Validate", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String validate,
    @WebParam(name = "Shared", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    ItemSearchRequest shared,
    @WebParam(name = "Request", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    List<ItemSearchRequest> request,
    @WebParam(name = "OperationRequest", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<OperationRequest> operationRequest,
    @WebParam(name = "Items", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<List<Items>> items);
```

It requires that I pass a lot more parameters than just the one it does in the example and it gives and error when compiling. Do I need to use a different setting for generating the java code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use amazon-ecs.jar for amazon product api

Answer (score -2):

I think much better to use official aws sdk for java: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/

Comment: As far as I can tell the Amazon sdk for java does not have the Amazon Product advertising SDK included.

Comment: Ooohhh, sorry, I didn't know that